# Create a structure of folders

Tags: c++, visual-studio, winapi

I'm trying to create a folder structure, for example something like this:

```
c:\game\user\user_profile\...
```

But when I'm using the `CreateDirectory()` function, it doesn't seem to be doing what I want it to do. I imagine I'm using it incorrectly, and I would really appreciate a quick explanation on what the function is actually doing. Here's my code:

```
void CreateDir(const char* path) {

    if (!CreateDirectory(path, NULL))
    {
        cout << "Fail";
        return;
    }
    else
        cout << "Success?";
}

int main()
{
    CreateDir("c:\\game\\user\\user_profile");
    system("pause");
}
```

It seems that the function allows me to create a single folder fine (*game*), and then allows me to add 1 more folder inside it (`user` - I assume it's because it knows where `game` is), but if I try to include more than 1 folder to the directory, it seems to fail.

I want to be able to create a structure of folders using this function, but it doesn't seem to work.

Again I'm sure I'm using this function incorrectly here, could someone advise?

Comment: you need create inner folders one by one. no another way. if you check error code - you will view `ERROR_PATH_NOT_FOUND` - [*One or more intermediate directories do not exist. This function only creates the final directory in the path. To create all intermediate directories on the path, use the SHCreateDirectoryEx function.*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-createdirectoryexa)

Comment: @RbMm that should be posted as an answer

Answer (score 1):

If you are using C++ 17 `filesystem` library is part of the standart library so you can use it like this:

```
#include <filesystem>

std::filesystem::create_directories("c:\\game\\user\\user_profile");
```

And if you are using g++ you need to add "-std=c++17" and "-lstdc++fs" flags.